# Can $Y_t= X_t - t X_1 -(1-t)X_0$ be Gaussian without $(X_t)$ being Gaussian?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, gaussian

Let $Y_t= X_t - t X_1 -(1-t)X_0$ be a sample-continuous stochastic process defined on $[0,1]$. If $(Y_t)$ is Gaussian, does it imply that $(X_t)$ is Gaussian on $(0,1)$ ?

It feels wrong but I am unable to construct a counterexample.

Here are some preliminaries:

A time continuous stochastic process $\left\{X_{t} ; t \in T\right\}$ is Gaussian if and only if for every finite set of indices $t_{1}, \ldots, t_{k}$ in the index set $T$,
$$\mathbf{X}_{t_{1}, \ldots, t_{k}}=\left(X_{t_{1}}, \ldots, X_{t_{k}}\right)$$

is a multivariate Gaussian random variable. That is the same as saying every linear combination of $\left(X_{t_{1}}, \ldots, X_{t_{k}}\right)$ has a univariate Gaussian distribution.

Using characteristic functions of random variables, the Gaussian property can be formulated as follows: $\left\{X_{t} ; t \in T\right\}$ is Gaussian if and only if, for every finite set of indices $t_{1}, \ldots, t_{k}$, there are real-valued $\sigma_{\ell j}, \mu_{\ell}$ with $\sigma_{j j}>0$ such that the following equality holds for all $s_{1}, s_{2}, \ldots, s_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$
\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{E}\left(\exp \left(i \sum_{\ell=1}^{k} s_{\ell} \mathbf{X}_{t_{\ell}}\right)\right)=\exp \left(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{\ell, j} \sigma_{\ell j} s_{\ell} s_{j}+i \sum_{\ell} \mu_{\ell} s_{\ell}\right) .
\end{equation*}
where $i$ denotes the imaginary unit such that $i^{2}=-1$.
The numbers $\sigma_{\ell j}$ and $\mu_{\ell}$ can be shown to be the covariances and means of the variables in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counterexample: Suppose, that
$$X_t = W_t + tZ,$$
where $W_t$ is a Gaussian proces and $Z$ is any non-Gaussian random variable (independent of $W_t$), then $X_t$ is not Gaussian, however
\begin{align*}
Y_t &= X_t - tX_1 - (1-t)X_0 \\
    &= (W_t + tZ) - t(W_1+Z) - (1-t)(W_0+0) \\
    &= W_t - tW_1 - (1-t)W_0
\end{align*}
is indeed a Gaussian proces.